# Redirect specific requests to a specific interface in linux

Tags: linux, networking, route

I have two networking interfaces on my Linux machine, `eth0` and `eth1`.
`eth0` is the default interface that some addresses are blocked on this interface.
How can I redirect the requests to blocked addresses to `eth1` or how can I configure a browser to use `eth1`?

I'm using this method: Using below command I add a route

```bash
sudo ip route add <network-address-1> via <gateway-ip-1> dev eth1
```

Then I create SSH proxy, address of the SSH server(`<remote-host>`) is in the `<network-address-1>`:

```bash
ssh <username>@<remote-host> -D 1080
```

And connect using a browser.

Is there another way without using the SSH proxy?

Update:

- `eth0` and `eth1` are on different subnets.
- Some addresses are blocked by firewall in my workplace that I use `eth0` for connecting. We use another device to connect to normal internet.
- `eth1` is another device that connects me to internet with different internet provider which do not blocks me.
- I need to use `eth1` when I want to connect websites that are blocked by the internet provider on `eth1`.

Comment: What do you mean "blocked"? How are they blocked? With `iptables`?

Comment: Some information is missing; please add it to your question. Are `eth0` and `eth1` on the same subnet? Where are the sites blocked: on the system or on a gateway/router/firewall upstream? Are the blocked sites subnets or just a list of individual hosts? Do you know why these sites are blocked?

Comment: @LjmDullaart Thank you for your response, I updated my question

Comment: @aviro I firewall are used in my workplace. I updated my question with extra informations

Comment: hm. Then why don't you use the gateway on `eth1` as default gateway, and possibly add specific routes for the internal network towards the gateway on `eth0`'s network? Note that `iptables` would allow you to route packets based on user, but not onn process. If you can run the browser under a specific userID, that could be a solution.